# Is there a way for an ultralight or powered glider to smoothly enter a jet stream?

Tags: approach, glider, experimental-aircraft, ultralight, windshear

Once inside the jet stream altitude 7-15 km is it all that turbulent or is there a way to enter it smoothly for an ultralight plane or a powered glider? [More info](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24420/can-a-giant-kite-carrying-a-person-fly-around-the-world-by-riding-jet-streams)

Comment: From [SKYbrary](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Jet_Stream): "*Not all jet streams are turbulent but aircraft exploiting the tailwinds afforded by a Jet Stream often experience light to moderate turbulence for much of the flight. This turbulence can sometimes be severe and has on at least one occasion led to the death of a passenger [...] Jet Streams passing over mountains usually produce waves of considerable amplitude and this increases the risk of turbulence.*"

Comment: The greater question might be: *is the jet stream above the absolute ceiling of the aircraft in question?*

Comment: @JonathanWalters: That's not impossible in theory, current altitude record for a glider: [15,460m](http://www.fai.org/fai-record-file/?recordId=14043).

Comment: I can't see a pressurized aircraft still being considered an ultralight

Comment: @TomMcW  only the pilot is pressurized.

Comment: @Jen Are you talking something like a space suit? Even at that a pressurization system of any kind would probably make the weight too high for it to be considered an "ultralight." Even the FAA's definition of the slightly broader term "light sport aircraft" specifies "unpressurized." A glider could do it as mins points out. Of course, the legality and licensing requirements would be a different story but I think you're just talking hypothetically

Comment: @TomMcW more like a high altitude jump suit.

Comment: There might be exceptions, but the ultralights I have seen so far ar not certified above FL095 in the EASA jurisdiction.

Comment: The current 15460-meter glider height record was made with pressurized suits. But it is only 500 meters higher than Harris' previous record from 1986, which was done with just an oxygen mask.

Comment: Paragliders regularly fly above  FL95 in the Himalayas. I know of at least one flight where FL225 was reached. The boundary between normal and jet stream air does not sound like the place where I would chose to put a Paraglider. Large differences in wind speed on an aircraft flying at a 25mph airspeed that is dependent on smooth laminar airflow to maintain its wing shape does not lead to good outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height is not the barrier. People have flown off Mount Everest - see http://abcnews.go.com/Travel/paragliding-everests-peak-kayaking-indian-ocean/story?id=21097292 as one example - though not when the jet stream is blowing over/around the mountain.

The problem is at the boundary layer between jet stream and none jet stream air when the aircraft only have air speeds of 20-50mph. The mixing of air, and the sudden hit of jet stream air speed will be well in excess of the gliders max air speed.

It has however been done in a hot air balloon. http://www.businessinsider.com/richard-branson-on-hot-air-ballooning-2014-10?IR=T

Comment: What kind of gliders are you talking about when you say 'aircraft only have air speeds of 20-50mph'? The gliders I have flown have Vne at the excess of 160mph. The powered gliders I fly have cruise speeds of 100mph.

Comment: Ultralights based on hangliders have cruise speeds in the 20-40mph.

Comment: In that case could you modify your wording so that it would read 'in excess of the hanggliders max air speed' instead?